# Increment NSNumber inside the GCD Block

Tags: objective-c

How can I increment the NSNumber which is inside the GCD block:

```
  -(void) doSomethingIntensive:(NSNumber *) value
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[value intValue] + 1];

    });
}
```

Comment: C is still pass by value.

Comment: And `NSNumber` is still not an `int`.

Comment: What is C?? I cannot change the value variable since it is inside the block. I need to somehow mark it as a __block variable but where!

Comment: "What is C?" - I hope that wasn't serious.

Comment: C is a letter of the alphabet... I kid! lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers inherited from a block are considered "read-only". In order to modify the value you need to prefix it with `__block`. In your case you cannot prefix `value` with `__block` because it's an argument. Even if you could, your GCD block is asynchronous, and would return before your CGD block was called.

For what you're trying to do, you need to do something like this:

```
- (void)doSomethingIntensive:(NSNumber *)value complete:(void (^)(NSNumber *result))complete
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        if (complete) complete(@(value.integerValue + 1));
    });
}
```

You would call such a function like this:

```
[doSomethingIntensive:@(1) complete^(NSNumber *result) {
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
});
```

The general idea is when your "intensive operation" is done, it calls your callback.

Comment: `NSInteger *result` - why/how that?

Comment: So have to use a completion block. Is there no way to change the passed in value.

Comment: I dont want a complete handler. If I am passed value as NSNumber I want to change the same value.

Comment: @CodaFi True! Effectively "read-only" in the sense that the original can't be changed.

Comment: @johndoe You have to. Your GCD block is asynchronous. Your function would return before the GCD block started.

Comment: @H2C03 It was a typo, was supposed to be `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

The *value* pointer is double copied: once when you pass it to the function, another time when you pass it to the block. To go around this you have to pass a pointer to pointer, so that you're able to modify the original pointer value:

```
-(void) doSomethingIntensive:(NSNumber **) valueRef
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        if(valueRef)
            *valueRef = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[*valueRef intValue] + 1];
    });
}
```

Be careful with race conditions, if you need to use the point in the main queue, then you need to protect it's access with a mutex.